# C# Discord bot get senders avatar

Tags: c#, discord.net

Hi I was wondering if anyone knew how to make my c# bot get a senders avatar and then have it reply with the users avatar in the message.
Here is what I have:

```
    [Command("testuser")]
    public async Task testuser()
    {
        EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();

        builder.WithTitle("Message response")
            .WithDescription("Message" + **SENDERS USER AVATAR HERE**);

        await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build());
    }
```

I tried using:

`.withurl() and .withimageurl()`combined with `Context.User.GetAvatarUrl and Context.User.AvatarId`

But none of those worked, please help

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/003d2.jpg) is an example of what I want it to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EmbedBuilder.WithDescription()` doesn't allow you to add images to the content of an embed's description, if what you want is for the embed to look like the screenshot you linked, then you have to use

```
builder.WithFooter($"Help requested by {Context.User.Username}", Context.User.GetAvatarUrl());
```